# Restructuring mappings to remove a header when inner map is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to provide a list of chronologically ordered items with a date header like this:

[image]

I use the below to generate that example:

```
  {this.state.datesarray.map(date => {
    return(
      <div>
      <DateHeader date={date} />
      {this.state.events
        .filter(event => event.date
          .includes(date))
          // .filter(event => event.favourite == 1)
          .map(filteredEvent =>(
            <Events event={filteredEvent} />

          )
        )
      }
      </div>
    )
  })}
```

This present no problems. However if I want to filter on the value `event.favourite == 1` (currently commented) I end up with the below result. The header is rendered even when there are no results in the subsequent mapping.

How can I restructure this such that the heading is also removed?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because you're rendering the date header, then filtering and sometimes winding up with an empty list.

The solution would be to avoid rendering the header until you know if you have something to render... unfortunately, your code will need to be restructured to do the filtering before you start to render. Something like this:

```
{this.state.datesarray.map(date => {
  // filter the events
  const events = this.state.events
    .filter(event => event.date
      .includes(date))
      // .filter(event => event.favourite == 1)
    );

  // check if there are any events to report
  return events.length > 0
    ? (
          <div>
              <DateHeader date={date} />
              {events.map(filteredEvent => (
                  <Events event={filteredEvent} />
              ))}
          </div>
      )
    : null;
}
```

Comment: That was super close. If you get rid of the `.map(filteredEvent =>(<Events even={filteredEvent} />` I'll accept it incredibly thankfully.